# Linq not execute as expected

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have a function to get all users from table named users in database which the `user_id` is not contained in table `user_ingroup` like below:

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult DisplayUser(int? page, string groupId, string searchName, string searchPosition, string searchOffice)
{
        try
        {
            if (null == db)
            {
                db = new vien_kiem_soat_streammingEntities();
            }

            var UserIds = from p in db.user_ingroup.Where(p => p.group_id == groupId) select p.user_id;
            var users = db.users.Where(m => !UserIds.Contains(m.id));

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchName))
            {
                ViewData["searchName"] = searchName;
                users = users.Where(us => us.full_name.ToLower().Contains(searchName.ToLower()));
            }

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchPosition))
            {
                users = users.Where(us => us.position.Contains(searchPosition));
                ViewData["searchPosition"] = searchPosition;
            }

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchOffice))
            {
                users = users.Where(us => us.office.Contains(searchOffice));
                ViewData["searchOffice"] = searchOffice;
            }

            ViewData["users"] = users.OrderBy(m => m.full_name).ToPagedList(page ?? 1, 2);

            var positions = from p in db.users.Where(p => !UserIds.Contains(p.id)) select p.position;
            List<string> pos = positions.Distinct().ToList();

            ViewData["positions"] = pos;
            ViewData["group"] = groupId;

            return View("DisplayUser");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Redirect(Url.Action("Login", "Login", null));
        }
}
```

Everything works perfectly, if all parameters that are passed to this function are null, but if one of them has a value, the function returns all users no matter the user is already in group or not.

Could anyone please explain me how could this happen and how to resolve this?

Comment: what you meant by _Everything work perfectly if all parameters that is passed to this function are null_ ?

Comment: I meant that if int? page = null and groupId =null and  searchName =null and searchPosition = null and searchOffice = null I will get all users in table named users but id of the users that I get are not contained in table "user_ingroup".

Comment: `var users = db.users.Where(m => !UserIds.Contains(m.id));` gives you users whose id is not present in `user_ingroup` right ? `!` is typo ? so when groupId is null, `!UserIds.Contains(m.id)` will evaluate to true for all users.

Comment: yes.................!

Comment: Yes, I forgot to pass GroupId in some case. it is working now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `groupId` is `null`, `UserIds.Contains(m.id)` will always evaluate to `false` and that is what is intended. Hence it looks culprit here is `!` operator in below line..

```
var users = db.users.Where(m => !UserIds.Contains(m.id));
```